# How to display multiple values per x using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, multiple-columns

I have data like the following:

```
9.22896 11.071  6.09602 4.17486 4.36179 3.9716  2.59873 2.17187 6.03572 2.79591
6.09602 10.6492 8.04082 9.37753 6.03572 9.22896 6.65753 5.30243 6.03572 2.79591
9.37753 8.04082 8.10267 6.09602 10.6492 8.04082 4.74732 6.61385 8.44901 5.95602
6.61385 8.04082 8.07195 9.54263 6.12163 9.25815 8.04082 8.04082 9.22896 8.04082
...
```

I would like to plot that using gnuplot. 
The goal is to show, that the values in each row converge to a certain value and that the values get better over time.

I could try plotting each column with `plot '-'` but as there should be several hundred up to a thousand columns this would not be very useful.

My understanding of gnuplot is very basic and I was not quite sure on what to search for.

If it helps I can reorder the input values but I don't think that will help a lot.

Comment: So is the row or column the time axis?

Comment: Rows are the time axis. At each time there are several hundred data points. I finally figured it out using a for loop in gnuplot. Should I put that up here or is it too obvious to be helpful to others?